# LaTeX command returning its argument unalteredly

Tags: macros

I would like to define a new command, called `\datum{}`, which returns its argument without any modification: e.g., `\datum{5}` gives `5` without any change in format. Could you please help me how to construct such a command?

Comment: I can't figure out why you have to define such a useless command.

Comment: `\let\datum\relax` could have that effect

Comment: No, this is what I wanted to perform. Thank you very much!

Comment: The purpose of this command is that I can search through the data of the tex document and can easily check and correct them.

Comment: @Roli (+1) A nice idea!

Comment: Is it permissible to assume that the argument of `\datum` consists only of "ordinary" characters (letters, numerals, and punctuation marks)? Or could the argument also contain TeX-special characters such as `{`, `}`, `&`, `#`, `%`, etc? Will the argument contain only ASCII-encoded characters, or could it contain more general `utf8`-encoded characters? Please advise.

Comment: This command would serve as to denote the numbers (perhaps numbers given with Latin letters) in the tex document.

Comment: The 'usual' way I guess would be `\newcommand*{\datum}[1]{#1}` (the LaTeX kernel has a similar `\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}`). But this is going to be a macro call and so the usual restrictions w.r.t. special characters (category codes etc.) apply. There are some subtleties involved here, for example `\datum{5}` will work as expected, but `\datum{\verb|_|}` will not. `\let\datum\relax` or `\newcommand*{\datum}{}`, which do not make `\datum` a macro *with an argument* would work here.